# Ограничение отдачи файла по умолчанию

Tags: nginx

Как узнать, есть ли какие либо ограничение на скорость отдачи файла в nginx?

Comment: Посмотреть в конфиг на предмет директивы limit_rate?

Comment: В конфигурационном файле nginx, ни о каких лимитах не упоминается

Comment: Отдаю файлы mp4, у меня конфиг по умолчанию. Быть может есть какие настройки, торые улучшили скорость или что еще, чтобы максимум пользователей могли смотреть видео без подвисаний?

Comment: Так может вы банально в сеть упираетесь?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчания worker_processes=1 рекомендую проверить и поставить auto. Остальные рекомендации по улучшению производительности Nginx есть [тут](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/).

Answer (score 1):

Какая у вас сеть?

Грубо говоря для видео у вас поток в bps = размер файла в Мб * 1024 * 1024 * 8

Кол-во одновременно подключенных пользователей = пропускная способность сети в Мб/с * 1024 * 1024 / (поток в bps)